# Deploying Datahub using maven and spring boot

Tags: marklogic-9

I am trying to deploy MarkLogic datahub framework through spring boot project using maven . But not getting enough examples. Can someone please help here..

I have already downloaded the datahub  java code but I also want to deploy data hub though it.

I have downloaded from 
https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub

Comment: Data hub uses Gradle for maintenance tasks, but you can invoke Gradle from Maven as well. Perhaps give https://github.com/raphw/gradle-maven-plugin a try?

Comment: I tried invoking gradle from maven but the plugin seems missing in maven central. Also was able to create a pure spring boot project using maven there was no need for using gradle also .